# How can I convert this jQuery code to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want convert following working jQuery code into JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txt1").keydown(function(event){
        var keyPress=String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        var Keycode=event.keyCode;
        alert("KeyPress : "+keyPress)
        alert("KeyCode : "+Keycode)   
    })
})
```

and I am trying this to replace this code with JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("txt1").onkeydown=function(event){
    var keyPress=String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    var Keycode=event.keyCode;
    alert("KeyPress : "+keyPress)
    alert("KeyCode : "+Keycode) 
}
```

and this above code not working.

Comment: `document.getElementById("txt1").addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { ... });`

Comment: which part doesn't work?

Comment: @baao Are you going to post this as an answer or should I ?

Comment: To be clear, jQuery **is** JavaScript. jQuery is a JavaScript library.

Comment: feel free to post it @KobyDouek

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("txt1").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keyPress = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    keyCode = e.keyCode;    
    alert("KeyPress : " + keyPress)
    alert("KeyCode : " + keyCode)  
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer